# How to get the plots from the Gamma function

Tags: plotting

I downloaded the notebook about the Gamma function from Wolfram Mathworld : see
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/SpecialFunctions/GammaFunction.nb

Get some errors : how to fix this ?

Gamma[z] function plotting for 3 situations : Real, Imginair and as modulus of z

`Timing[ComplexPlot3D[Gamma[z], {z, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100, ClipFill -> None, Mesh -> False]]`

`Timing[ComplexPlot3D[Gamma[z], {z, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100, ClipFill -> None, Mesh -> False]]`

First  i must repair de plots and then adding them in a plotarray

Comment: *Get some errors : how to fix this ?* ---> What do the errors say?

Comment: I suppose it's totally unexpected to find examples (with `Gamma[]`!!!) in the documentation for `ComplexPlot3D`....You've been learning this stuff (WL/Mathematica), and I appreciate the progress you've made. The progress is apparent (to me, at least). However, do the basic research. Look up the basic syntax for `ComplexPlot3D`.

Comment: I had a quick look at the notebook and it invokes a package. Please make sure that you have downloaded said package properly, such that you can load it

Comment: The package Utilities seems to  present on my computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional package is no longer required.

```
ComplexPlot3D[Gamma[z], {z, -5 - 3 I, 5 + 3 I},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 Mesh -> False,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {
     HoldForm[Re[z]],
     HoldForm[Im[z]],
     HoldForm[Abs[Gamma[z]]]}),
 PlotLegends ->
  BarLegend[Automatic,
   LegendLabel -> HoldForm[Arg[Gamma[z]]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: That is a interesting looking plot. If you cross section over the x axis , you will get a 2D Gamma [s] plot. This is a nice introduction to the Zeta[s] function. 
Its only that i must learn to interpret legend coloring